# scalac- create jar file from a scala file and its dependency

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jar, compilation

Using **scalac** only and not sbt can I create a runnable jar file from a scala file "script.scala" and a dependent library "x.jar"?

This article https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-create-executable-jar-file-scalac-run-scala/ says to create the jar by:-

```
scalac script.scala -d script.jar
```

How do I include my dependent library x.jar here?

When I do the below I do not see x.jar when I extract script.jar

```
scalac -classpath "x.jar" script.scala -d script.jar
```

Comment: Creating a JAR is not job of `scalac` you would need to run the `jar` tool from the JDK... but really, why? Just add a simple **sbt** build definition.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez 
I was exploring to see if an executable jar file could be created just by using scalac alone. I will take your advice and try sbt.